Java ProcessBuilder replaces Unicode characters in commands by '?'. How can I avoid that?
I have a Java importer application that is executed via a scheduler (also from me) by usage of ProcessBuilder. The scheduler passes a file path to the started application as an argument in the process builder's commands. Now, if that file path contains Chinese characters for example, it will end up with ? replacements for all of them when received in the started application's main method args array.
I looked for this and found a lot about parameters file.encoding and sun.jnu.encoding and the LANG environment variable, but in the end I was not able to find a solution. So I discussed it extensively with ChatGPT, and in the end wrote a small Test class, but all to no avail:
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class CodesetTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("sun.jnu.encoding"));
        System.out.println(System.getenv("LANG"));
        System.out.println(System.getenv("JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS"));
        
        System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");
        System.setProperty("sun.jnu.encoding", "UTF-8");
        System.out.println("Properties changed!");
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("sun.jnu.encoding"));
        
        if (args.length == 0) {
            String filePath = "C:/temp/示例.txt";

            ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(
                "java",
                "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8", 
                "-Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8", 
                "-cp", System.getProperty("java.class.path"), 
                CodesetTest.class.getName(), 
                filePath
            ).inheritIO();

            processBuilder.environment().put("LANG", "en_US.UTF-8");
            processBuilder.directory(new File("C:/temp"));

            try {
                Process process = processBuilder.start();
                System.out.println("Started new process: " + processBuilder.command().stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
                int retVal = process.waitFor();
                System.out.println("Result: " + retVal);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("File path received: " + args[0]);
        }
    }
}

Here is the output on my machine:
UTF-8
Cp1252
en_US.UTF-8
null
Properties changed!
UTF-8
UTF-8
Started new process: java, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8, -cp, C:\Users\MRE\workspaces\pdtt\TestProject\bin, CodesetTest, C:/temp/示例.txt
UTF-8
UTF-8
en_US.UTF-8
null
Properties changed!
UTF-8
UTF-8
File path received: C:/temp/??.txt
Result: 0

I thought the file path would be changed by Windows and/or Java when that string is passed as an argument, because the process builder seemed to still have the correct characters when starting the process. If I understood correctly the posts and discussions I read, the system's charset is used for that. So I tried to overwrite that charset explicitly for the started process. That did change the otherwise used cp1252 in the sun.jnu.encoding parameter to UTF-8 for the second started JVM, as I hoped.
But, it didn't fix my problem. Then I thought it may be the writing side, so the process builder when it creates the actual "command line command" before it is executed may change it, at least it originally has the cp1252 as seen in the output. So, I tried to set the respective properties before I call the process builder, but again, that didn't work, as you can see.
Now I am a bit lost and out of ideas. Basically, my goal is, no matter what the system settings are, and where the machine is located, to support passing file paths to my importer application that contain Unicode characters, like these Chinese ones.
Can anybody explain what I am doing wrong, or what the issue is that prevents this from working?

Try it in Powershell. Before you execute it, run [Console]::InputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding  Of course, the font will have to support the characters in question too

...and the "LANG" environment variable... That will do you no good - it's a Unix thing and you're running Windows [ which is your real problem ;) ]

Which version of Java was this?  Do you get different results if you run with Java 23?


try chcp 65001 on the console to set it to UTF-8; 2) if previous works (does for me), Change default code page of Windows console to UTF-8  or  Is it possible to set "locale" of a Windows application to UTF-8?


Run Command  chcp in CMD.exe or PowerShell. I guess it is not 936, maybe 437 ?

Thank you for your suggestions! A few remarks on that from me: The application is run by customers and they do have their system as it is (sometimes it's Windows), so the approaches to change the local settings of machines like the Beta-Checkbox for UTF-8 in cosole windows or generally the cmd/powershell charset might solve the problem per machine, but may not be feasible for all customers. Apart from that the application is built and running with Java 17, I haven't evolved it to 23, yet. I am looking for a programmatical solution, if possible. Otherwise I need to find a workaround.

You might have to go for partial automation, e.g. write something to check their environment and take it from there. e.g. what version of Powershell they are using (possibly a better way of getting your Unicode support)

Ok, generally changing the Windows setting, the Beta-checkbox referenced by user85421, does solve the problem indeed. Then the read file path argument contains the correct characters. Since I in my code don't - nor the customers manually - execute cmd or the powershell and the code simply calls the java command via the Process Builder with the arguments, I am not sure if I can actually take that possible advantage of powershell. Sure I may try to call the powershell executable and somehow run java executable with/in it, but I am not sure about that. Does that make sense?

Yes, I'm not a Powershell person, but afaik it stops the execution of scripts by default as a security measure which won't help you much ;) But the checkbox thing might be automated. Everything's about Registry entries so that will simply change one

Interesting. Ignoring the ProcessBuilder part, when I run your sample as java CodesetTest.java C:/temp/示例.txt with JDK17/18 it prints corrupt characters, whereas JDK11/14/19/21/22/23 all print 示例.txt correctly - all from same cmd window (chcp 65001) on my Windows 11 UTF-8 (beta-checkbox ticked) machine. So there is something different with charset handling of JDK17+18 with the others. Try testing in JDK21.
